# Merge objects with same key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time, if i have an array of objects like so:

```
var my_array = [
    Object {Project: A, Hours: 2},
    Object {Project: B, Hours: 3},
    Object {Project: C, Hours: 5},
    Object {Project: A, Hours: 6},
    Object {Project: C, Hours: 9}
]
```

I want to merge all the objects with the same key together into one object, such that their hours get added up:

Expected output:

```
my_array = [
    Object {Project: A, Hours: 8}
    Object {Project: B, Hours: 3}
    Object {Project: C, Hours: 14}
]
```

How can I approach this issue? It has taken me a long time to get my data formatted in this way, this is the last step!

My attempt, I get that I am looping through array, not sure how to deal with the merging of the objects:

```
for (var i =0; i<my_array.length; i++) {
   my_array[i].Project   // access the object project key
   my_array[i].Hours     // need to increment hours
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **your attempt**, you are missing out on creating a new array

```
var newArray = [];
var uniqueprojects = {};
for (var i =0; i<my_array.length; i++) {

   if ( !uniqueproject[my_array[i].Project] )
   {
     uniqueproject[my_array[i].Project] = 0;
   }
   uniqueproject[my_array[i].Project] += my_array[i].Hours;
   //my_array[i].Project   // access the object project key
   //my_array[i].Hours     // need to increment hours
}
```

Now create the final output array out of uniqueproject map

```
newArray = Object.keys(uniqueproject).map(function(key){return {Project:key, Hours:uniqueproject[key]}});
```

Comment: FYI I just tested your code on jsPerf and compared it to the other proposed solution and yours is much faster. See my post below.

Answer (score 7):

You create another object where you can actually group the projects and accumulate the corresponding hours, like this

```
var groups = my_array.reduce(function(resultObject, currentObject) {

    // if this is the first time the project appears in the array, use zero as the
    // default hours
    resultObject[currentObject.Project] = resultObject[currentObject.Project] || 0;

    // add the current hours corresponding to the project
    resultObject[currentObject.Project] += currentObject.Hours;

    return resultObject;
}, {});
```

At this point, your `groups` will look like this

```
console.log(groups);
// { A: 8, B: 3, C: 14 }
```

Now, you just have to expand this object, like this

```
var result = Object.keys(groups).map(function(currentGroup) {
    return {Project: currentGroup, Hours: groups[currentGroup]};
});
```

Now, the result will be

```
[ { Project: 'A', Hours: 8 },
  { Project: 'B', Hours: 3 },
  { Project: 'C', Hours: 14 } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `thefourtheye`'s and `gurvinder372`'s proposed solutions work, so I set up a benchmark test on [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) to test which is faster. You can see it [here](http://jsperf.com/merge-objects-with-same-key-in-javascript).

It appears that `gurvinder372`'s code is by far the fastest.

P.S. please ignore the `Uncaught TypeError` as it is a jsPerf issue currently being fixed that has nothing to do with the results of the test. For more info, see [this](https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com/issues/45) and [this](https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com/issues/64).