# How to search same values from the dynamic array and also sum that values using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a dynamic object like :

```
 [ 
  { age: 35 },
  { weight: 60 },
  { age: 50 },
  { weight: 54 },
  { height: 175 },
  { age: 3.5 }
]
```

I want to find and the sum same value like that:-

```
 [ 
  { age:88.5 },
  { height: 175 },
  { weight: 114 }
 ]
```

Comment: Haven't you tried anything?

Comment: No validated answer here, but it could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262445/merge-object-sum-a-single-property-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge objects with same key in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147321/merge-objects-with-same-key-in-javascript)

Comment: Try doing something, search "walking json" or "traverse" https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/dealing-with-complex-objects-in-javascript-with-walk-js-a5826c64569f

Comment: Why does the result is an array of object with a single property which, if the code works properly, should be unique keys? You should store it in a single object: way easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach()` to make an iteration on array and another iteration on object element and calculate the sum.

```js
let sum = {};
const data = [
    { age: 35 },
    { weight: 60 },
    { age: 50 },
    { weight: 54 },
    { height: 175 },
    { age: 3.5 }
]

data.forEach((item) => {
    for (let key in item) sum[key] = sum[key] ? sum[key] + item[key] : item[key]
})

console.log([sum])
```

Also we can use [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to calculate the sum.

```js
    const data = [
        { age: 35 },
        { weight: 60 },
        { age: 50 },
        { weight: 54 },
        { height: 175 },
        { age: 3.5 }
    ]

let sum = data.reduce((all, curr) => {
    let key = Object.keys(curr)[0];
    all[key] = all[key] ? all[key] + curr[key] : curr[key]
    return all
}, {})

console.log([sum])
```

Comment: This is the perfect case for `.reduce()` ;)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon yes, I didn't think it. :)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I tried it with reduce but I was unable to get any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try  this

```js
const data  =   [ 
  { age: 35 },
  { weight: 60 },
  { age: 50 },
  { weight: 54 },
  { height: 175 },
  { age: 3.5 }
];

const result  = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, ele)=> {
const key  = Object.keys(ele)[0];
acc[key]  = (acc[key]||0)+  ele[key]; return acc},[]))
.map(([k, v])=>({[k]:v}))

console.log(result);
```